I'm not able to call the azue document intelligence api using the latest api version "2024-02-29-preview"
Using the code below I'm not able to call the latest api version "2024-02-29-preview" of the Azure AI Document Intelligence using prebuilt-layout. I'm in the correct region west europe where the version is available. The reason I want to use the newest version is as it supports figure extraction.
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import DocumentAnalysisClient

document_analysis_client = DocumentAnalysisClient(
    endpoint=endpoint, credential=AzureKeyCredential(key)
)


poller = document_analysis_client.begin_analyze_document_from_url('prebuilt-layout', formUrl, locale='de')
result = poller.result()

>>> print(result.api_version)
'2023-07-31'

I get the '2023-07-31' version and the method documentation doesn't indicate any keyword or parameter to be used to specifiy the version.
Just trying calling the method begin_analyze_document_from_url like
poller = document_analysis_client.begin_analyze_document_from_url('prebuilt-layout', formUrl, locale='de', api_version="2024-02-29-preview")

results in the Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-professional/387/plugins/python/helpers-pro/pydevd_asyncio/pydevd_asyncio_utils.py", line 117, in _exec_async_code
    result = func()
             ^^^^^^
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
...
azure.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: (404) Resource not found
Code: 404
Message: Resource not found

I know that the fact the parameter is not implemented is causing the error, but where is the package implementing the functionality to specifically call the right API version. Can anybody help with that?

So it seems the DocumentAnalysisClient currently doesn't support preview API versions which is fine. Using REST works, starting with the examples in the documentation

According to this doc the Document Intelligence  2024-02-29-preview  REST API is now available. This preview API introduces new and updated capabilities:

Public preview version  2024-02-29-preview  is currently available only in the following Azure regions:

East US
West US2
West Europe



Install the library using pip
pip install azure-ai-documentintelligence==1.0.0b2
pip install azure-ai-formrecognizer


Get started with Azure AI Document Intelligence latest preview version (2024-02-29-preview) reference doc


from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import DocumentAnalysisClient
from azure.core.exceptions import HttpResponseError

# Replace these values with your actual endpoint and key
endpoint = "<your-endpoint>"
key = "<your-key>"

# Sample document URL
formUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-REST-api-samples/master/curl/form-recognizer/sample-layout.pdf"

try:
    # Create Document Analysis client
    document_analysis_client = DocumentAnalysisClient(
        endpoint=endpoint, credential=AzureKeyCredential(key)
    )

    # Analyze the document layout
    poller = document_analysis_client.begin_analyze_document_from_url('prebuilt-layout', formUrl, locale='de')
    results = poller.result()

    # Process the analysis results
    print("Document analysis results:")
    print(results)

except HttpResponseError as e:
    print("HTTP Response Error:", e.response.status_code, e.message)

except Exception as ex:
    print("An unexpected error occurred:", ex)


Output:


Thanks for your response. In your case it's also using the current GA API version AnalyseResult(api_version=2023-07-31, ....

It is possible to override the API version while initialising the DocumentIntelligenceClient to use a different version than the one that the Python client library was developed for.
However, please note that Microsoft warns that:

overriding this default value (for api_version) may result in unsupported behavior

The below code sample shows using the api_version to override the API version from 2024-02-29-preview to 2024-07-31-preview while using the 1.0.0b2 version of the azure-ai-documentintelligence client library.
# pip install azure-ai-documentintelligence==1.0.0b2
from azure.ai.documentintelligence import DocumentIntelligenceClient
document_intelligence_client = DocumentIntelligenceClient(
            endpoint = <<Your endpoint>>,
            credential = <<Your credential>>,
            api_version = "2024-07-31-preview"
        )

Also, note that Microsoft is yet to release an official client library that targets the 2024-07-31-preview version of the API. However, once they do release the official client library supporting the 2024-07-31-preview version of the API, we should update to that version of the client library and remove the api_version parameter while initialising the document intelligence client.
